# How do you deploy a QT app to Apple's Test Flight?

Tags: qt, qt5, testflight

I can't seem to find any information on how you deploy a QT app to Apple's Test Flight or Apple's App Store.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: For an iOS Qt app, I used qmake's XCode generator to create an xcode project and built it with XCode. From there, I just used the standard xcode tools to upload to test flight and then app store.

Comment: Perfect Nikos. Thank you!